# php how to get dynamically created textbox for onblur function

Tags: php

I am fetching details from database and showing in same page,I have to update value on blur of weight column. My problem is onblur not working. Please look into the blur function code below,kindly help. :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <?php 
        include "dbconfig.php";
        include "yrsetup.php";      
        $ttable='lot'.$yr;
    ?>
    <style>

    </style>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.1.js"></script>
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#tdate").change(function(){
        var tdate = $(this).val();
            $.post("lotno.php",
                     {
                         tdate: tdate
                     },
                     function(data,status){
                         $("#target-content").html(data);
                         //alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
            });         
        });

        $("#target-content").change(function(){
        var tlotno = $(this).val();
        var tdate = $("#tdate").val();
//alert(tlotno);        
        $.post("getdet.php",
                     {
                         tlotno: tlotno,
                         tdate: tdate
                     },
                     function(data,status){
                         $("#gtdet").html(data);
                         //alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
            });         
        });
///////////////////

////////////////////////////////
    $(".bweight").blur(function(){
    var text = $(this).val();
    alert(text);
/*  id = $(this).closest('.mob').attr('data-id');
            $.post("mobupdate.php",
                 {
                     id: id,
                     text: text
                 },
                 function(data,status){
                        // $("#target-content").html(data);
                        //  alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
                 });            
 */ 
 });

});


</script> 

</head>
    <body>


enter code here

    <form>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Select Date:<input type="date" id='tdate' name='tdate' >
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Select A/P/C:
                            <select name='apcslct' class='apcslct'>
                                <option>A</option>      
                                <option>P</option>      
                                <option>C</option>                                      
                            </select>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        Select LotNo:
                        <select id="target-content"></select>
                    </td>
                </tr>               
            </table>
            <div id="gtdet">

            </div>  
        </form>

    </body>
</html>



getdet.php

<?php 
    include "dbconfig.php";
    include "yrsetup.php";      
    $ttable='lot'.$yr;

    $tdate1=$_POST['tdate'];
    //$tdate1=date('d-m-Y');
    $tdate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($tdate1));

    $tlotno=$_POST['tlotno'];

    //echo $tdate;
        $sql="SELECT lotno,asmsoc,$ttable.acno,CONCAT(assami.frst,' ',assami.send,' ',assami.thrd,' ',assami.vilg) AS ename,
        $ttable.sacno,sno,apcd,allcodes.name AS iname,nobgs,kqty,kore,$ttable.rate,purno,pur.`send` as purnm,nqty AS weight 
        FROM $ttable 
        LEFT JOIN assami ON assami.mrk IS NULL AND  $ttable.acno=assami.acno
        LEFT JOIN allcodes ON allcodes.sw='IT'  AND $ttable.`apcd`=allcodes.cd
        LEFT JOIN pur ON pur.mrk IS NULL AND $ttable.purno=pur.`acno`
        WHERE $ttable.mrk IS NULL AND  date1='$tdate' AND atoz='$tlotno' AND asmsoc='A' UNION ALL
        SELECT lotno,asmsoc,$ttable.acno,society.ename AS ename,
        $ttable.sacno,sno,apcd,allcodes.name AS iname,nobgs,kqty,kore,$ttable.rate,purno,pur.`send` as purnm,nqty AS weight 
        FROM $ttable 
        LEFT JOIN society ON society.mrk IS NULL AND  $ttable.acno=society.acno
        LEFT JOIN allcodes ON allcodes.sw='IT'  AND $ttable.`apcd`=allcodes.cd
        LEFT JOIN pur ON pur.mrk IS NULL AND $ttable.purno=pur.`acno`
        WHERE $ttable.mrk IS NULL AND  date1='$tdate' AND atoz='$tlotno' AND asmsoc='S' ORDER BY lotno ";

    $res=mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);
    if($res == FALSE) {
       die(mysqli_error($mysqli)); // TODO: better error handling
    }else{
        //printf("Select returned %d rows.\n", $res->num_rows);
    }
    $row=mysqli_fetch_array($res);
?>
<table border="1px">
<tr>
    <th>
        LOtno
    </th>
    <th>
        A/S
    </th>
    <th>
        Acno
    </th>

    <th>
        Name
    </th>
    <th>
        SubNo
    </th>
    <th>
        Sno
    </th>
    <th>
        Icode
    </th>
    <th>
        Item
    </th>
    <th>
        Bags
    </th>
    <th>
        Kqty
    </th>
    <th>
        Kore
    </th>
    <th>
        Rate
    </th>
    <th>
        PCode
    </th>
    <th>
        PName
    </th>
    <th>
        Weight
    </th>

</tr>
<?php
    do{
?>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="text" disabled="disabled" name="lotno" class="lotno" value="<?php echo $row['lotno']; ?>" data-id="<?php echo $row['lotno'];?>" style="width:30PX" >
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php echo $row['asmsoc'];?>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php echo $row['acno'];?>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php echo $row['ename'];?>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php echo $row['sacno'];?>     
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php echo $row['sno'];?>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php echo $row['apcd'];?>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php echo $row['iname'];?>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php echo $row['nobgs'];?>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php echo $row['kqty'];?>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php echo $row['kore'];?>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php echo $row['rate'];?>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php echo $row['purno'];?>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php echo $row['purnm'];?>
    </td>
        <?php if ($row['weight']>0){ ?>
            <td>
                <input type="number" class="bweight" value="<?php echo $row['weight'];?>" style="border:none;" onblur="blr(this);" >
            </td>
        <?php } else { ?>
        <td >
            <input type="number" class="bweight" style="border:none;" onblur="blr(this);">
        </td>
        <?php } ?>
    </td>   
    </td>
</tr>   
<?php
    }while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)); 
?>  
</table>
```

Comment: are you getting any error in Console ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with Upgraded jQuery i.e jQuery 1.7+  [jQuery On](http://api.jquery.com/on/) inside `$(document).ready` Or you can use `live` instead of `on`:

```
$("body").on("blur",".bweight",function(){
    var text = $(this).val();
    alert(text);
 });
```

Comment: thank you sir now its working. but continuously alert message is showing its taking  .bweight class which is applicable for all row how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Hello @NarayanBhat! Could you please share your code with jsFiddle. Or please explain what you want to achieve with `blur`?

Comment: i want to update weight column to database. instead of posting its keep on showing alert messages because of same class is referred to all table rows . im new to stack overflow so i don't know how to link jsFiddle code.

Comment: yes i know sir. my problem is in getdet.php i am passing same class name .bweight for all table row.when i refer .bweight function  keep on showing next text box value i have to forcefully close the window. below is my code where i am passing .bweight                                                                                <td >
            <input type="number" class="bweight" style="border:none;" onblur="blr(this);">
        </td>

Comment: @NarayanBhat ! You may use `console.log()` to show your selected values on `blur()` to check if your code is working fine or not?

Answer (score 1):

You are using jQuery 1.6. The on() function is not available yet. Use live() instead : http://api.jquery.com/live/